# Symfony2, where can I put a global class?

Tags: symfony, bundle

I am developing a quit simple website, with just some text. The text need to be editable by the user, so I am storing the text in a database. Because of that, i need to access to my Doctrine entity from every bundle, so where do I need to write that entity ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

All your entities are accesible across your app if you you use namespaces.

Just create it, for example, at `Your\WhateverBundle\Entity\Myentity` and in every controller you must add: `use Your\WhateverBundle\Entity\Myentity;`

I think that's you are looking for, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it works, but if I do that, then the bundle where I will develop my Entity is going to be needed for all my website, and is not going to be independant anymore... That's my I was looking for a way to develop an entity reusable and independant of any bundle...

Comment: Symfony2 is developed like a "Bundle of Bundles", all depends on a Bundle. All you need to work with a independent Bundle is to load it in your AppKernel's `registerBundles` method: `new Your\WhateverBundle\YourWhateverBundle(),` and the you can work with all entities in that Bundle.